# How to make style not apply to children elements?

Tags: html, css

I am making a mega dropdown menu and for the main menu I have a certain style listed below but I would like this style to only apply to the very first list which is the main menu. I don't want it to apply to any of the lists in the mega dropdown menu is there a way of doing this with out having to override these styles in the children lists?

```
#main-nav ul li {
width: 12.5%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
line-height: .9em;
font-weight: bold;
border-left: 2px solid #33363b;
background: #25272a;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#main-nav ul li a {
display: block;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 12px;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 22px 0;
text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav ul li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #3B8DBD;
cursor: pointer;
background: #191a1c;
}
```

Comment: Look at the [child selector `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

Comment: I was trying to do that, but where do I? I placed it between the ul > li and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You have to chain `>` from something unique (so not `ul`) to your target element, like `#main-nav > ul > li`. `ul > li` is useless, because every `li` in your menu is a `ul > li`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
#main-nav > ul > li {
width: 12.5%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
line-height: .9em;
font-weight: bold;
border-left: 2px solid #33363b;
background: #25272a;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#main-nav > ul > li > a {
display: block;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 12px;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 22px 0;
text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav > ul > li > a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #3B8DBD;
cursor: pointer;
background: #191a1c;
}
```